# How do I convert a .png image to a Byte Array - Android, TFLITE application

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I have made a **TFLITE** model and am using **Google's ML KIT** to access it from my mobile application. I have run into trouble with trying to get my data into the `byte[1][299][299][3]` format that I need for feeding to my classifier.

I was trying to arrange a `bytestream` into that format but I don't know if it's feeding `left-right`, `top-bottom`, R-G-B, etc.

Can anyone point me to some documentation I can read about parsing `.png` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your .png file to an Android `Bitmap` using a `BitmapFactory` and an `InputStream`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```

With your Bitmap, you can also get the color of a pixel at a specified position. Unfortunately, the color is returned as `int`, which you have to decompose to your RGBA values. For that, see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color

Comment: Thanks @vollkorntomate. I've been running in circles through the documentation for hours trying to figure out what I need.